# Which approach for ensuring outbound email flows?

Tags: sharepoint-server, outgoing-email, smtp

We are using SharePoint App server as our Outbound SMTP server for Outgoing email. Emails are not consistently flowing.

Any recommendations for either:

1. Having a batch file set to run every couple hours to restart the  SMTP service or
2. Rebooting the App server if so, how frequently?

Comment: First, I would consider moving the SMTP relay to another non-SharePoint server. It'll be easier to diagnose. Can you supply an SMTPSVC log? Are the EMLs stuck in the Queue folder?

Comment: Trevor, Yes. I found a log file for yesterday - not sure how to interpret it though. Bear with me, I'm the one person in my non-profit agency of over 2000 employees that supports our on prem SharePoint. Once I manually restarted the SMTP service yesterday the emails were sent, leading me to believe they were stuck in the Queue folder.